# Creating box plots from a count (or frequency) table

Tags: python, boxplot, pandas

I have a census data where the number of population at each age is indicated and I am trying to create a box plot for the age of the entire population. At first I tried to repeat the 'age' by the number of population belonging to the specific age.

However, since there are millions of people in each country I am trying to investigate, this way of doing is very inefficient. I would like to know if there is a better way to do so.

I also tried to calculate the descriptive statistics from the frequency table first. However, somehow this was not easy either, probably due to my lack of knowledge in pandas. (Plus, I am relatively new in programming in the first place)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you in advance.